# Running XAPP1079 on a Zynq Board

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I am trying to run the XAPP 1079 on a Zynq Board (xc7z010clg400-1). Because the profile is not originally made for this specific board, I had to make some changes. I follow all the insructions for the Vivado and the SDK, but in the end after the board boots from the microSD card I don't see anything in the terminal. I was wondering first if the changes that I made are correct and if anymore are needed.

One specific issue I am having is that while creating an instance of the Zynq7 processor, it uses the configuration preset for the ZC702 board. Can/Should I change that?

```
# Create instance: processing_system7_0, and set properties
  set processing_system7_0 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:processing_system7:5.5 processing_system7_0 ]
  set_property -dict [ list CONFIG.PCW_CORE1_IRQ_INTR {1} CONFIG.PCW_USE_FABRIC_INTERRUPT {1} **CONFIG.preset {ZC702}**  ] $processing_system7_0
```

Also, while running the tcl scripts a warning appears.

```
[BD 41-1731] Type mismatch between connected pins: /ila_0/probe2(undef) and /irq_gen_0/IRQ(intr)
```

You can see the files for this profile [here](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/XAPP1079+Latest+Information).

Below are the two files that I have created after modifying the Xilinx ones. I should add that I'm using the 2017.1 version of Vivado.

create_bd_701.tcl

```
################################################################
# This is a generated script based on design: design_1
#
# Though there are limitations about the generated script,
# the main purpose of this utility is to make learning
# IP Integrator Tcl commands easier.
################################################################

################################################################
# Check if script is running in correct Vivado version.
################################################################
set scripts_vivado_version 2017.1
set current_vivado_version [version -short]

if { [string first $scripts_vivado_version $current_vivado_version] == -1 } {
   puts ""
   puts "ERROR: This script was generated using Vivado <$scripts_vivado_version> and is being run in <$current_vivado_version> of Vivado. Please run the script in Vivado <$scripts_vivado_version> then open the design in Vivado <$current_vivado_version>. Upgrade the design by running \"Tools => Report => Report IP Status...\", then run write_bd_tcl to create an updated script."

   return 1
}

################################################################
# START
################################################################

# To test this script, run the following commands from Vivado Tcl console:
# source design_1_script.tcl

# If you do not already have a project created,
# you can create a project using the following command:
#    create_project project_1 myproj -part xc7z010clg400-1
#    set_property BOARD_PART digilentinc.com:zybo:part0:1.0 [current_project]

# CHECKING IF PROJECT EXISTS
if { [get_projects -quiet] eq "" } {
   puts "ERROR: Please open or create a project!"
   return 1
}



# CHANGE DESIGN NAME HERE
set design_name design_1

# If you do not already have an existing IP Integrator design open,
# you can create a design using the following command:
#    create_bd_design $design_name

# Creating design if needed
set errMsg ""
set nRet 0

set cur_design [current_bd_design -quiet]
set list_cells [get_bd_cells -quiet]

if { ${design_name} eq "" } {
   # USE CASES:
   #    1) Design_name not set

   set errMsg "ERROR: Please set the variable <design_name> to a non-empty value."
   set nRet 1

} elseif { ${cur_design} ne "" && ${list_cells} eq "" } {
   # USE CASES:
   #    2): Current design opened AND is empty AND names same.
   #    3): Current design opened AND is empty AND names diff; design_name NOT in project.
   #    4): Current design opened AND is empty AND names diff; design_name exists in project.

   if { $cur_design ne $design_name } {
      puts "INFO: Changing value of <design_name> from <$design_name> to <$cur_design> since current design is empty."
      set design_name [get_property NAME $cur_design]
   }
   puts "INFO: Constructing design in IPI design <$cur_design>..."

} elseif { ${cur_design} ne "" && $list_cells ne "" && $cur_design eq $design_name } {
   # USE CASES:
   #    5) Current design opened AND has components AND same names.

   set errMsg "ERROR: Design <$design_name> already exists in your project, please set the variable <design_name> to another value."
   set nRet 1
} elseif { [get_files -quiet ${design_name}.bd] ne "" } {
   # USE CASES: 
   #    6) Current opened design, has components, but diff names, design_name exists in project.
   #    7) No opened design, design_name exists in project.

   set errMsg "ERROR: Design <$design_name> already exists in your project, please set the variable <design_name> to another value."
   set nRet 2

} else {
   # USE CASES:
   #    8) No opened design, design_name not in project.
   #    9) Current opened design, has components, but diff names, design_name not in project.

   puts "INFO: Currently there is no design <$design_name> in project, so creating one..."

   create_bd_design $design_name

   puts "INFO: Making design <$design_name> as current_bd_design."
   current_bd_design $design_name

}

puts "INFO: Currently the variable <design_name> is equal to \"$design_name\"."

if { $nRet != 0 } {
   puts $errMsg
   return $nRet
}

##################################################################
# DESIGN PROCs
##################################################################



# Procedure to create entire design; Provide argument to make
# procedure reusable. If parentCell is "", will use root.
proc create_root_design { parentCell } {

  if { $parentCell eq "" } {
     set parentCell [get_bd_cells /]
  }

  # Get object for parentCell
  set parentObj [get_bd_cells $parentCell]
  if { $parentObj == "" } {
     puts "ERROR: Unable to find parent cell <$parentCell>!"
     return
  }

  # Make sure parentObj is hier blk
  set parentType [get_property TYPE $parentObj]
  if { $parentType ne "hier" } {
     puts "ERROR: Parent <$parentObj> has TYPE = <$parentType>. Expected to be <hier>."
     return
  }

  # Save current instance; Restore later
  set oldCurInst [current_bd_instance .]

  # Set parent object as current
  current_bd_instance $parentObj


  # Create interface ports
  set DDR [ create_bd_intf_port -mode Master -vlnv xilinx.com:interface:ddrx_rtl:1.0 DDR ]
  set FIXED_IO [ create_bd_intf_port -mode Master -vlnv xilinx.com:display_processing_system7:fixedio_rtl:1.0 FIXED_IO ]

  # Create ports

  # Create instance: ila_0, and set properties
  set ila_0 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:ila:6.2 ila_0 ]
  set_property -dict [ list CONFIG.C_ENABLE_ILA_AXI_MON {false} CONFIG.C_MONITOR_TYPE {Native} CONFIG.C_NUM_OF_PROBES {4}  ] $ila_0

  # Create instance: irq_gen_0, and set properties
  set irq_gen_0 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:user:irq_gen:1.1 irq_gen_0 ]

  # Create instance: processing_system7_0, and set properties
  set processing_system7_0 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:processing_system7:5.5 processing_system7_0 ]
  set_property -dict [ list CONFIG.PCW_CORE1_IRQ_INTR {1} CONFIG.PCW_USE_FABRIC_INTERRUPT {1} CONFIG.preset {ZC702}  ] $processing_system7_0

  # Create instance: processing_system7_0_axi_periph, and set properties
  set processing_system7_0_axi_periph [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:axi_interconnect:2.1 processing_system7_0_axi_periph ]
  set_property -dict [ list CONFIG.NUM_MI {1}  ] $processing_system7_0_axi_periph

  # Create instance: rst_processing_system7_0_100M, and set properties
  set rst_processing_system7_0_100M [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:proc_sys_reset:5.0 rst_processing_system7_0_100M ]

  # Create instance: vio_0, and set properties
  set vio_0 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:vio:3.0 vio_0 ]
  set_property -dict [ list CONFIG.C_NUM_PROBE_IN {0}  ] $vio_0

  # Create interface connections
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net processing_system7_0_DDR [get_bd_intf_ports DDR] [get_bd_intf_pins processing_system7_0/DDR]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net processing_system7_0_FIXED_IO [get_bd_intf_ports FIXED_IO] [get_bd_intf_pins processing_system7_0/FIXED_IO]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net processing_system7_0_M_AXI_GP0 [get_bd_intf_pins processing_system7_0/M_AXI_GP0] [get_bd_intf_pins processing_system7_0_axi_periph/S00_AXI]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net processing_system7_0_axi_periph_M00_AXI [get_bd_intf_pins irq_gen_0/S_AXI] [get_bd_intf_pins processing_system7_0_axi_periph/M00_AXI]

  # Create port connections
  connect_bd_net -net irq_gen_0_IRQ [get_bd_pins ila_0/probe2] [get_bd_pins irq_gen_0/IRQ] [get_bd_pins processing_system7_0/Core1_nIRQ]
  connect_bd_net -net irq_gen_0_slv_reg [get_bd_pins ila_0/probe1] [get_bd_pins irq_gen_0/slv_reg]
  connect_bd_net -net irq_gen_0_vio_rise_edge [get_bd_pins ila_0/probe0] [get_bd_pins irq_gen_0/vio_rise_edge]
  connect_bd_net -net processing_system7_0_FCLK_CLK0 [get_bd_pins ila_0/clk] [get_bd_pins irq_gen_0/S_AXI_ACLK] [get_bd_pins processing_system7_0/FCLK_CLK0] [get_bd_pins processing_system7_0/M_AXI_GP0_ACLK] [get_bd_pins processing_system7_0_axi_periph/ACLK] [get_bd_pins processing_system7_0_axi_periph/M00_ACLK] [get_bd_pins processing_system7_0_axi_periph/S00_ACLK] [get_bd_pins rst_processing_system7_0_100M/slowest_sync_clk] [get_bd_pins vio_0/clk]
  connect_bd_net -net processing_system7_0_FCLK_RESET0_N [get_bd_pins processing_system7_0/FCLK_RESET0_N] [get_bd_pins rst_processing_system7_0_100M/ext_reset_in]
  connect_bd_net -net rst_processing_system7_0_100M_interconnect_aresetn [get_bd_pins processing_system7_0_axi_periph/ARESETN] [get_bd_pins rst_processing_system7_0_100M/interconnect_aresetn]
  connect_bd_net -net rst_processing_system7_0_100M_peripheral_aresetn [get_bd_pins irq_gen_0/S_AXI_ARESETN] [get_bd_pins processing_system7_0_axi_periph/M00_ARESETN] [get_bd_pins processing_system7_0_axi_periph/S00_ARESETN] [get_bd_pins rst_processing_system7_0_100M/peripheral_aresetn]
  connect_bd_net -net vio_0_probe_out0 [get_bd_pins ila_0/probe3] [get_bd_pins irq_gen_0/VIO_IRQ_TICK] [get_bd_pins vio_0/probe_out0]

  # Create address segments
  create_bd_addr_seg -range 0x10000 -offset 0x78600000 [get_bd_addr_spaces processing_system7_0/Data] [get_bd_addr_segs irq_gen_0/S_AXI/reg0] SEG_irq_gen_0_reg0


  # Restore current instance
  current_bd_instance $oldCurInst

  save_bd_design
}
# End of create_root_design()


##################################################################
# MAIN FLOW
##################################################################

create_root_design ""
```

create_proj_701.tcl

```
# Create project
set proj_name project_1
create_project -force $proj_name ./$proj_name

# Set project properties
set obj [get_projects $proj_name]
set_property "part" "xc7z010clg400-1" $obj
set_property "target_language" "Verilog" $obj
set_property board_part digilentinc.com:zybo:part0:1.0 $obj

# Set the directory path for the new project
set proj_dir [get_property directory $obj]

set_property ip_repo_paths  $proj_dir/../../src/my_ip [current_fileset]
update_ip_catalog

#create BD
source $proj_dir/../../src/scripts/create_bd_701.tcl
validate_bd_design
save_bd_design

#Create top wrapper file
make_wrapper -files [get_files $proj_dir/$proj_name.srcs/sources_1/bd/design_1/design_1.bd] -top
import_files -force -norecurse $proj_dir/$proj_name.srcs/sources_1/bd/design_1/hdl/design_1_wrapper.v

#implement the design and create bit file
launch_runs impl_1 -to_step write_bitstream
wait_on_run -timeout 60 impl_1

#Export design to SDK
file mkdir $proj_dir/$proj_name.sdk
file copy -force $proj_dir/$proj_name.runs/impl_1/design_1_wrapper.sysdef $proj_dir/$proj_name.sdk/design_1_wrapper.hdf
launch_sdk -workspace $proj_dir/$proj_name.sdk -hwspec $proj_dir/$proj_name.sdk/design_1_wrapper.hdf
```

Comment: it is clear which FPGA you are using. The question is: which board?

Comment: I'm using [this](http://store.digilentinc.com/zybo-zynq-7000-arm-fpga-soc-trainer-board/) board.

Comment: This is a Zybo. You should use the files related with this specific board and generate the right device tree

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? There are no related files for this board in the Xilinx profile.

Comment: http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/ click on this link, follow the instructions, build the kernel selecting the right files of the board, create your device tree, your image and so on. Everything is explained step by step

Comment: tutorial: http://80.93.56.75/pdf/0/7/6/4/8/07648722.pdf

Comment: I am not currently interested in booting a version of Linux on the board. And as far as the LED tutorial, I have already created my own crude version. What I am interested in, is having two bare-metal applications on the two cores of the ARM processor, and as far as I have searched I haven't found a version of them for my board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make XAPP1079 run on Zybo with changes in the tcl script responsible for the block design and some changes in the c file that the CPU0 runs.

As far as the tcl script for block design is concerned, I copied the configs from the [configuration preset](https://github.com/Digilent/ZYBO/tree/master/Resources/Preset) for the Zybo and pasted them in the property list of the instance of processing_system7_0 in the code.

Here is the code snippet. It is abbreviated because it is too large to post.

```
# Create instance: processing_system7_0, and set properties
  set processing_system7_0 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:processing_system7:5.5 processing_system7_0 ]
  set_property -dict [ list CONFIG.PCW_DDR_RAM_BASEADDR {0x00100000}  \
    CONFIG.PCW_DDR_RAM_HIGHADDR {0x1FFFFFFF}  \
    .
    .
    .
    CONFIG.PCW_PLL_BYPASSMODE_ENABLE {0}  \
    CONFIG.preset {Default*}\
    ] $processing_system7_0
```

As far the .c file for CPU0, I followed [this](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/XAPP1079-in-Vivado-2015-4/m-p/770827/highlight/true#M42032) post.

I changed the part that would reset CPU1,

```
{
/*
*  Reset and start CPU1
*- Application for cpu1 exists at 0x00000000 per cpu1 linkerscript
...
...
...
}
```

with this code.

```
#define CPU1STARTADR 0xfffffff0
#define sev() __asm__("sev")

print("CPU0: writing startaddress for cpu1\n\r");

print("CPU0: writing startaddress for cpu1\n\r");
Xil_Out32(CPU1STARTADR, 0x00200000);
dmb(); //waits until write has finished

print("CPU0: sending the SEV to wake up CPU1\n\r");
sev();
```

Now when I debug the application projects in the SDK, I can see continuous Hello Worlds from both CPUs. Despite that the part of the application note about the interrupt doesn't seem to work.